# receiving data from pc to PIC 16F877A with compiler hi-tech

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart

I try to send the data from pc to the pic microcontroller. I am a beginner in PIC.
I send the data from hyperterminal and the data will display in the led in port B of PIC.

I used 10Mhz clock and the connection in 9600 baudrate.

here my uart.h program:

```
 char UART_Init(const long int baudrate)
 {
unsigned int x;
x = (_XTAL_FREQ - baudrate*64)/(baudrate*64);
if(x>255)
{
    x = (_XTAL_FREQ - baudrate*16)/(baudrate*16);
    BRGH = 1;
}
if(x<256)
{
  SPBRG = x;
  SYNC = 0;
  SPEN = 1;
  TRISC7 = 1;
  TRISC6 = 1;
  CREN = 1;
  TXEN = 1;
  return 1;
}
return 0;
}

 char UART_TX_Empty()
{
  return TRMT;
 }

char UART_Data_Ready()
 {
  return RCIF;
 }
 char UART_Read()
{

   while(!RCIF);
   return RCREG;
 }

 void UART_Read_Text(char *Output, unsigned int length)
 {
    int i;
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    Output[i] = UART_Read();
  }

 void UART_Write(char data)
 {
  while(!TRMT);
 TXREG = data;
 }

 void UART_Write_Text(char *text)
 {
  int i;
   for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
      UART_Write(text[i]);
 }
```

and this is my main program:

```
 #include<htc.h>
 #include<pic.h>
 #define _XTAL_FREQ 10000000 //Clock Frequency
 #include "uart.h"

void main()
{
   TRISB = 0x00; //PORTB as Output
   UART_Init(9600);
do
   {
    if(UART_Data_Ready())       
    PORTB = UART_Read();
 __delay_ms(1000);

   }while(1);
 }
```

in hyperteminal I send data say 10010010 but the led in port B do not respond, are there any error in my program?

Answer (score 0):

You have several steps: initialize UART, initialize LEDs, communicate over UART and setup your PC's UART. Which components have you successfully written and tested? You say you're a beginner, so what is the smallest functional program you have successfully executed on a PIC? I've been working with microcontrollers for years, but I still schedule about a whole day to get a single LED to turn on because it could be a software problem, a hardware problem, a voltage problem, an oscillator problem, a PCB problem or a compiler problem.

Here are the steps I take for microchip bring up:

1. Go over the oscillator section, the configuration bits section, the watchdog section and the pinout section (looking for `VDD` and `VSS`) in the datasheet. These are some of the hardest parts to get right. (A gotcha about the oscillator: just because you can program a chip, doesn't mean the oscillator is working because the programmer provides it's own clock.)
2. Write the bare-minimum code to turn on a single LED.
3. Write the bare-minimum code to make the LED blink (just use a for-loop delay for now, timers come later)
4. Write UART initialization code and transmit a single character, I use captial U because it's pretty in binary. `TXREG = 'U';`
5. Connect the UART to a PC and see if the hyperterminal sees the `U`. If it doesn't, I connect an oscilscope to the lines to make sure that the PIC is transmitting, that the PC transmits when I type characters and that the timing of the edges matches.
6. Within the PIC code, have the UART echo characters from the terminal. (`TXREG = RXREG;`), and then type on the hyperterminal and make sure the characters are echoed back.

One more note:

Do not have the PIC perform the `SPBRG` calculation. PIC16 are 8-bit processors and 10000000 requires 32-bits to store. There might be hiccups with the integer divison. It might not have a bug in it, but there's no need to have the PIC calculate it each time. Calculate it before-hand and hard-code the value.

Comment: I just done simple I/O programming with pic, I will check the program as your suggestion. thank you